# Adding source control to Azure Log Analytics Workspace Functions

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

Has anyone found a solution to adding source control to Azure Log Analytics Workspace Functions? (KQL queries saved on the Azure GUI)

I have a number complex queries and I would like to track changes over time. So far my searches have not come up with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure has a vast support in REST API

[Docs / Log Analytics / Saved Searches / Saved Searches - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/saved-searches/create-or-update)